# Do not interpolate newline characters in curl response in strings

Tags: json, bash, zsh

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how to *not* interpolate escape characters in strings ... particularly those that are returned from a `curl` response.  I am fetching data that looks like:

```
{"foo":"bar\r\nbaz"}
```

On its own, `curl resource` will print out the above no problem.  However, if I use command substitution as in `echo $(curl resource)`, it will emit:

```
{"foo":"bar
baz"}
```

I am trying to use node to parse the JSON as in:

```
node -e "console.log(JSON.parse('$(curl resource)'))"
```

however it chokes on the interpolated newline characters as well it should because these are not valid in JSON.

I've tried:

```
node -e $'console.log(JSON.parse(\'$(curl resource)\'))'
# Shell syntax error on the second `$`
node -e $'console.log(JSON.parse(\''$(curl resource)$'\'))'
# Fails to parse JSON due to newline
```

How can I prevent command substitution from interpolating the escape characters.

Comment: The double quoted version should work just fine. What do you get if you run `var=$(curl resource); echo "$var"; declare -p var`?

Comment: @EtanReisner `echo "$var"` prints the newline characters (not shocking).  `declare -p var` yields `typeset var='{"foo": "foo\r\nbar"}'` which is of course more in line with what I want.

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry, I did run `echo "$var"` the first time I just mistyped it in the above comment

Comment: That sounds like you have literal newline bytes in the output and not escaped characters. What do you see in the response if you use the `--trace` option to curl? Also is this zsh or bash because they differ slightly here (your test output seems to indicate zsh I think)?

Comment: @EtanReisner `curl --trace` output: https://gist.github.com/ajcrites/47febe365b9be8129f71 and I am using `zsh` (should have made that clearer).  A solution in `bash` is also perfectly acceptable since I want this for a script where I can specify the interpreter.

Comment: This appears to be a zsh problem. Try this all in bash and it should work. I'm not sure why zsh is expanding the escaped newlines like that but it seems to be doing that. Compare this `/bin/bash -c 'f='\''bar\r\nbaz'\''; echo +$f+; echo "+$f+"; declare -p f'` to this `/bin/zsh -c 'f='\''bar\r\nbaz'\''; echo +$f+; echo "+$f+"; declare -p f'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

As for the `echo` problem:

**`echo` in `zsh` by default *does* expand backslash escape sequences** such as `\n`, which is what POSIX prescribes (but note that `zsh` in general often deviates from POSIX).

Contrast this with `bash`, and `ksh` (depending on the underlying `/bin/echo` utility's behavior), which by default do *not* (there you need to use the nonstandard `-e` option to turn on such expansion).

Thus, **to print a string *as is*, the *portable approach* is to use `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo`**, which guarantees that backslash escape sequences are treated as *literals*:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(curl resource)"
```

As an alternative that only works in `zsh` and `bash`, you can use

```
echo -E "$(curl resource)"
```

---

As for the `node -e` problem:

You must escape the `\` instances in `curl`'s output to prevent them from being interpreted as backslash escape sequences by *`node`*:

```
node -e "console.log(JSON.parse('$(curl resource | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')'))"
```

If you want to avoid escaping, pass the `curl` command's output via *stdin*:

```
curl resource | 
  node -e 'console.log(JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync("/dev/stdin", "utf-8")))'
```

Comment: Particularly the interpretation of escape sequences by the node interpreter was the problem. I wish there were another setting rather than having to use `sed` in this way, but it's a good enough solution.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Glad to hear it; I've just added a stdin-based solution that bypasses the need for escaping.